# Create custom dashboard for plugin

Tags: widgets, dashboard

I am trying to create in admin area my own Dashboard for my plugin. Only article I found is an example in [WP Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dashboard/) but the widgets cannot be moved. I suspect that loading script code in this article is incorrect:

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'dashboard' );
    wp_admin_css( 'dashboard' );
    add_thickbox();
```

Shouldn't there be a path to the script? But where to find it?
Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)—in this case, `dashboard`—is the handle of the script. The handle can be pre-registered using [`wp_register_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/), and that's where the script's path will be set.

`dashboard` isn't one of the [default scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-and-js-libraries-included-and-registered-by-wordpress) that WordPress registers, but it's entirely possible some other entity has registered it.

Looking at [the example code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dashboard/#user-contributed-notes) that you're working from, you can't just snip the three lines in your question out and use them in your code. You'd need to take the entire sample provided and modify it to suit your purposes.

Comment: Of course I used wp_register_script() and as I wrote the code from the example works, it's just obvious that it's not getting the jscript. I didn't want to paste the code from the whole example here.